# how to write data in rows in a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write data in csv file.

I have written it like this:
`617.png 0,988.png 0,850.png 0,824.png 0,536.png 0`

But I want to write the data in the file like this

```
617.png 0
988.png 0
850.png 0
824.png 0
536.png 0
```

Any help? this is my code:

```
import os
import cvutils 
import csv 
dir_unknown = 'UntitledFolder'
trainingSet='/home/irum/Desktop/CLUSTERING/UntitledFolder/UntitledFolder1'
#Create CSV File
images_names = []
SEPARATOR=" "

print"start"
label = 0
for (dirname, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(dir_unknown):
    print"dd"
    for subdirname in dirnames:
        subject_path = os.path.join(dirname, subdirname)
        print "subject_path",subject_path
        for filename in os.listdir(subject_path):
        abs_path = "%s" % (filename)
        images_names.append("%s%s%d" % (abs_path,SEPARATOR,label))
        with open('class_train22', 'wb') as myfile:
            wr = csv.writer(myfile,delimiter=',',quotechar='\\',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, lineterminator='\r\n')
            wr.writerow(images_names )
        label = label + 1
```

Comment: Do this `images_names.append("%s%s%d\n" % (abs_path,SEPARATOR,label))`

Comment: You're writing all the filenames in one go. You need to find a place in your code to iterate over the filenames and call `writerow` **once per filename**

Comment: Instead of building a list of `images_names`, it should be simpler to reverse the `for filename in os.listdir(subject_path):` and the `with open('class_train22', 'wb') as myfile:` parts to **1)** open a file in write mode, **2)** write one row for each `filename`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your csv file will have only 1 row since you're opening the same file for writing (truncate, not append).

You have to create a `with` block at the start, opening the file and creating the csv object once and for all, and all other statements go in the `with` block.

The `csv` file must be space delimited. Quoting will be done if spaces are found in filenames, no need to do anything else

```
with open('class_train22', 'wb') as myfile:  # python 2 only
#with open('class_train22', 'w',newline='') as myfile:  # python 3 only

    wr = csv.writer(myfile,delimiter=' ',quotechar='\\',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```

Then, write 1 row per filename + index couple, as a list. `csv` module handles the separation/quoting for you, no need to format a string.

the inner loop looks like this:

```
    for (dirname, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(dir_unknown):
        for subdirname in dirnames:
            subject_path = os.path.join(dirname, subdirname)
            for filename in os.listdir(subject_path):
                wr.writerow([filename,label])
                label += 1
```

You'll just have to adjust the incrementation of `label`, because you seem to expect 0 everywhere (so what's the use) whereas here you'll get an absolute number incrementing for all files of all dirs.